# How to keep color schemes when connecting through ssh in MobaXterm

Tags: ssh, mobaxterm

I have MobaXterm Personal edition v7.3. I changed the color scheme for my terminal to "Soft Pastel". It works great with the local terminal but everytime I log in to any remote server the default colors are back.

What can I do to keep the colors for all te terminals?

Thanks,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Did you try to change color scheme in the session settings ? (not in the global settings).
I have tested on mine (version Personal 7.6) and it is working.
Just right click on your saved session, edit session then terminal settings. Here change your color scheme and conect to your SSH server.

Paul

Comment: Thank you, you are right, each session saves a different configuration

Comment: How can i ensure the SSH path and box name (the prompt per line) keep the colour? before ssh i see this https://imgur.com/a/zQpZW3r then after ssh its just clear.